# copy data from selected country(row) and between two defined dates (columns) to worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a "selected file" worksheet into a already created worksheet called "Data". I want the user to be able to enter country name  ("B2") , start Date ("B3") in a separate worksheet called "SelectFile". On a button click...user allow to select excel file then the data pulled into the "Data" Worksheet, only including records between those dates in selected country (including the start and entry date).
I have tried the bellow code but still give an error in this line
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(selectedRow, dSDate), Cells(selectedRow, dEDate)).Copy

the selected file have many countries and attached in this link
[enter link description here](https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/api/data-preview.csv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv&filename=time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)
and user entery in the first sheet"SelectFile" image attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQhqN.png)
and my code attached

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Dim countryName As Variant
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lastcolumn As Long

Dim mainFile As Workbook
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim selectedRow As Long

Dim dSDate As Date, dEDate As Date
Dim lRowStart As Long, lRowEnd As Long
Dim aData() As Variant
Dim i As Long
```

'   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Set mainFile = ThisWorkbook

Sheets("SelectFile").Activate
Set mainSheet = ActiveSheet
countryName = Range("B2").Value
dSDate = Range("B3").Value
dEDate = Range("B4").Value

Sheets("Data").Activate
Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet





FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls,(*.csv*),*csv*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    
    Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcolumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = 1 To Lastrow
    
        If Cells(i, 2) = countryName Then
        
            selectedRow = i
            Exit For
        End If
        Next i
    For y = 1 To Lastcolumn
       If Cells(i, 1) = dSDate Then
        lRowStart = y
        Debug.Print "Start row = " & lRowStart
        Exit For
    End If
    Next y
    For y = 1 To Lastcolumn
    If Cells(i, y) = dEDate Then
        lRowEnd = y
        Debug.Print "End row = " & lRowEnd
        Exit For
    End If
Next y
    
    
   OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(selectedRow, dSDate), Cells(selectedRow, dEDate)).Copy
```

' OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B204:OC204").Copy

```
    mainFile.Activate
    dataSheet.Activate
    
    
  '  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SelectFile").Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
        OpenBook.Close False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: `If Cells(i, 1) = dSDate Then` should be `If Cells(i, y) = dSDate Then` and `OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(selectedRow, dSDate), Cells(selectedRow, dEDate)).Copy` has dates where it should be column numbers `lRowStart` and`lRowEnd`